# Second call to promise executes before the promise returns - Angular Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, es6-promise

I have the following pattern of code, where an update call is made each time the user updates the data on the view.

```
// FACTORY SERVICE CODE
.factory('updateService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var df = $q.defer();
    var updateData = function(uriName, dataObj){
        $http({
          method: 'PUT',
          data: dataObj,
          url: uriName
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('from put');
                console.log(response.data);
                df.resolve(response.data);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('Error', response.data);
                df.reject(response.data);
        });
        return df.promise;
    }
    return {updateData:updateData};
}])

// CONTROLLER CODE
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','updateService', function($scope, updateService) {
    $scope.saveToServer = function(){
        var tmpObj = {data: $scope.dataOne, anotherData: $scope.dataTwo};
        myService.updateData(uriName, tmpObj).then(function(resolved) {
            console.log('CONTROLLER');
            $scope.myData = resolved;
            console.log($scope.myData);
            console.log('end');
        }, function(rejected){
            console.log('put rejected');
        });
    });
    $scope.btnUpdateClick = function(){
        $scope.saveToServer();
    };
}]);
```

PROBLEM:
When the user makes an update request for the first time, the code works as expected. But when the user updates therein after, the "resolved promise" code (in the controller) executes FIRST and then the $http code (in the service) executes.

> SAMPLE OUTPUT of btnUpdateClick made TWICE with enough interval in-between:

```
from put
Array [ Object, Object]
CONTROLLER
Array [ Object, Object]
end
CONTROLLER
Array [ Object, Object]
end
from put
Array [ Object, Object]
```

QUESTION:
Kindly point me out where I'm making a mistake?

> Is the problem because of PUT request?

or is it possible to correct the execution queue as expected, through $apply or anything like that?

Comment: `var df = $q.defer();` move this code inside the `updateData` function
and another suggestion is that why you are creating seperate promise for $http call. Just return the $http promise.

Comment: @pragaas it would be better to accept answer after upvoting :)

Comment: @ARUN - rightly pointed out.

Comment: @JagajitPrusty - my reputation is too less to upvote :-S

Comment: @pragaas Now you can do :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the promise every time you call a function like below:

```
.factory('updateService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    var updateData = function(uriName, dataObj){
        var df = $q.defer(); //Changes here
        $http({
          method: 'PUT',
          data: dataObj,
          url: uriName
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('from put');
                console.log(response.data);
                df.resolve(response.data);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('Error', response.data);
                df.reject(response.data);
        });
        return df.promise;
    }
    return {updateData:updateData};
}])
```

In this way you are creating a new promise on every function call.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the ["explicit promise creation antipattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) here, and on top of that, trying to share a single deferred object among all your service calls.

Just get rid of the deferred and take advantage of promises' chaining properties and everything will be good:

```
.factory('updateService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var updateData = function(uriName, dataObj){
        return $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            data: dataObj,
            url: uriName
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('from put');
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Error', response.data);
            throw response.data;
        });
    };

    return {updateData:updateData};
}]);
```

Comment: Your approach of coding is absolutely correct. But since my question was regarding a fix for the mistake that I had in my code, I would like to have that solution as an answer, just for the record.
Good Job!

Comment: so very, much absolutely

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create a custom promise over here, though it is considered as bad practice.

> Is the problem because of PUT request?

It's not a problem related to PUT request. Your factory is using common `deferred` object and same has been returned from method. Once that `promise` object will get resolved, it will be always be in resolve state.

---

Rather I'd like to suggest you to utilize `$http.put` promise, and make your code smaller than what you had before.

```
var updateData = function(uriName, dataObj){
    return $http.put(uriName,dataObj)
}
```

Comment: Your approach of coding is absolutely correct. But since my question was regarding a fix for the mistake that I had in my code, I would like to have the other solution as an answer, just for the record.
Good Job!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
// FACTORY SERVICE CODE
.factory('updateService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var updateData = function(uriName, dataObj){
        var df = $q.defer();
        $http({
          method: 'PUT',
          data: dataObj,
          url: uriName
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('from put');
                console.log(response.data);
                df.resolve(response.data);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('Error', response.data);
                df.reject(response.data);
        });
        return df.promise;
    }
    return {updateData:updateData};
}])

// CONTROLLER CODE
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','updateService', function($scope, updateService) {
    $scope.saveToServer = function(){
        var tmpObj = {data: $scope.dataOne, anotherData: $scope.dataTwo};
        myService.updateData(uriName, tmpObj).then(function(resolved) {
            console.log('CONTROLLER');
            $scope.myData = resolved;
            console.log($scope.myData);
            console.log('end');
        }, function(rejected){
            console.log('put rejected');
        });
    });
    $scope.btnUpdateClick = function(){
        $scope.saveToServer();
    };
}]);
```

In your old code you was creating defer object only once so it was resolved /rejected only once. But what you need is to return promise each time and resolve/ reject it each time.

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful. Explain what it is that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Have patience  @Pointy

Comment: @JunedLanja ha ha well OK, but seriously explanations that clearly point out the particular lines of code that are the problem are very valuable.